# Why is my binary node equals method throwing an assertion error?

Tags: java, binary-tree, junit4, equals

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T> {

private BinaryTreeNode<T> left;
private BinaryTreeNode<T> right;
private T data;

public BinaryTreeNode(){
    this(null,null,null);
}

public BinaryTreeNode(T theData){
    this(theData,null,null);
}

public BinaryTreeNode(T theData, BinaryTreeNode<T> leftChild, BinaryTreeNode<T> rightChild){
    data = theData;
    left = leftChild;
    right = rightChild;

   @Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o instanceof BinaryTreeNode<?>) {
           BinaryTreeNode<?> n1 = (BinaryTreeNode<?>) o;
           if(this.getLeft() == null && n1.getLeft() == null && this.getRight() == null && n1.getLeft() == null) {
               return this.data == n1.getData();
           }
         if(this.getRight() == null && n1.getRight() == null && this.getLeft() != null && n1.getLeft() != null) {
             return this.data == n1.getData();
         }
         if(this.getLeft() == null && n1.getLeft() == null && this.getRight() != null && n1.getRight() != null) {
             return this.data == n1.getData();
         } else {

          return false;
         }
     }
}

public class BinaryTreeTesting {
BinaryTreeNode<Integer> node15 = new BinaryTreeNode<Integer>(5);
BinaryTreeNode<Integer> node2 = new BinaryTreeNode<Integer>(5);

  @Test
   public void testEqualsObjectNode() {
   assertTrue(node15.equals(node2));
   assertFalse(node1.equals(node2));

}
```

Please help me figure out why my equals method isn't passing my junit test. I did main method testing and it should be exactly the same I keep getting an assertion error. I even added a toString method to check and I'm getting the exact same string for both nodes so why is it claiming that it is not equal?

Comment: What's `node1`? Which test is failing?

Comment: @TedHopp assertTrue test is failing!

Comment: Are two entries equal if they have the exact same object, or if they are fundamentally equal? `==` compares to identical object, whereas an `equals` method would compare to if they are the same.

Comment: I think @Compass has diagnosed the problem. You should be using `this.data.equals(n1.getData())` everywhere you are using `==` to test data equality.

Comment: It isn't. Your *unit test methodi is. Be precise.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
if(this.getLeft() == null && n1.getLeft() == null && this.getRight() == null && n1.getLeft() == null) {
```

is incorrect, it should be

```
if(this.getLeft() == null && n1.getLeft() == null && this.getRight() == null && n1.getRight() == null) {
```

Secondly, in the second and third `if`s, you are not comparing to see if the left and right nodes are equivalent, respectivley. For example, on the second branch, you are only checking to see if right subtrees are not null and the left subtrees are null. But you don't check to see if the left subtrees are the same.

Thirdly, it looks like you are missing some curly brackets. Here is a working version of your code.

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T> {

    private BinaryTreeNode<T> left;
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> right;
    private T data;

    public BinaryTreeNode() {
        this(null, null, null);
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode(T theData) {
        this(theData, null, null);
    }


    public BinaryTreeNode(T theData, BinaryTreeNode<T> leftChild, BinaryTreeNode<T> rightChild) {
        data = theData;
        left = leftChild;
        right = rightChild;

    }

    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(BinaryTreeNode<T> left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(BinaryTreeNode<T> right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof BinaryTreeNode<?>) {
            BinaryTreeNode<?> n1 = (BinaryTreeNode<?>) o;
            if (this.getLeft() == null && n1.getLeft() == null && this.getRight() == null && n1.getRight() == null) {
                return this.data == n1.getData();
            }
            if (this.getRight() == null && n1.getRight() == null && this.getLeft() != null && n1.getLeft() != null) {
                return this.data == n1.getData();
            }
            if (this.getLeft() == null && n1.getLeft() == null && this.getRight() != null && n1.getRight() != null) {
                return this.data == n1.getData();
            } else {

                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;


    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        BinaryTreeNode<Integer> node15 = new BinaryTreeNode<Integer>(5);
        BinaryTreeNode<Integer> node2 = new BinaryTreeNode<Integer>(5);
        BinaryTreeNode<Integer> node1 = new BinaryTreeNode<Integer>(1);

        System.out.println(node15.equals(node2));
        System.out.println(node1.equals(node2) == false);

    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the test failures, since all nodes involved in the test apparently have `null` left and right nodes.

Comment: Ah, yes, OP is overriding the equals() function but only in one of the two constructors. He's not using that constructor in his test cases. Will update my answer.

Comment: @harshpatel991 wait what did you change?

Comment: @ari I added a closing bracket after `right = rightChild;`. I just tried my code and the output is `true
true` as expected